# How to get index of an element inside a div with class

Tags: jquery

I want to get the index of my element in the required div and not in the whole of the same classes divs.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.child').change(function() {
    var control = $(this);
    var grandParentContainer = '.grandParent';
    var parentContainer = '.parent';
    var grandParentIndex = control.closest(grandParentContainer).index();
    var parentIndex = control.closest(parentContainer).index();
    console.log(grandParentIndex, parentIndex);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wholeContainer">
  <section class="grandParent">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="grandTitle" placeholder="title">
    </div>
    <section class="parent">
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="parentTitle" placeholder="parent title">
        <select class="child">
          <option value="0">one</option>
          <option value="1">two</option>
          <option value="2">three</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section class="grandParent">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="grandTitle" placeholder="title">
    </div>
    <section class="parent">
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="parentTitle" placeholder="parent title">
        <select class="child">
          <option value="0">one</option>
          <option value="1">two</option>
          <option value="2">three</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```

the `grandParentIndex` is correct; but the `parentIndex` is fault.
for the first grandParent it's correct, but for more , it returns the index of parent in the whole of div('.container'). for example for the first parent of second grandParent , returns 3 and not 0; for the last parent , returns 4 and not 1;
what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the element again in the argument when using [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index) function, also, as you already store `$(this)` in `control` variable you don't have to wrap the variable again with jQuery later in the code, try this :

```js
$(function() {
  $('.child').click(function() {
    var control = $(this);
    var grandParentContainer = '.grandParent';
    var parentContainer = '.parent';
    var grandParentIndex = control.closest(grandParentContainer).index();
    var parentIndex = control.closest(parentContainer).index();
  console.log(grandParentIndex, parentIndex);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="grandParent">
    <div class="parent">
      <button class="child">click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <button class="child">click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <button class="child">click</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grandParent">
    <div class="parent">
      <button class="child">click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <button class="child">click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answering.I have edited the html code to my real one. your answer doesn't work on this

Comment: I changed the javascript, but still doesn't work. Can you please help me?

Comment: Given that you changed your HTML, now it's a different issue as it's a `select` element and not a `button` anymore, please rephrase your issue by editing the last part of your post so one can have a better idea of your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can call to `.index()` without arguments.

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements

<sup>https://api.jquery.com/index/#entry-longdesc</sup>

```js
$(function() {
  $('.child').click(function() {
    var control = $(this);
    var grandParentContainer = '.grandParent';
    var parentContainer = '.parent';
    var grandParentIndex = $(control).closest(grandParentContainer).index(grandParentContainer);
    var parentIndex = $(control).closest(parentContainer).index();
    console.log(parentIndex);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="grandParent">
    <div class="parent">
      <button class="child">click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <button class="child">click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <button class="child">click</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grandParent">
    <div class="parent">
      <button class="child">click</button>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <button class="child">click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answering.I have edited the html code to my real one. your answer doesn't work on this